# How can I convert time to integer on Javascript-ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a code like this:

```
if(sure !== undefined && sure !== "" && sure !== null){
        values.sure=X.baseFunc.timeIntoInteger(sure.substring(0,2),sure.substring(3,5));
}
```

and I want to convert time to integer. For example I want to convert 03:44 to integer. But when I run the code I got "substring not a function" error. How can I solve it ? or how can I write code for time to integer on Javascript/ExtJs.

I  wrote another code block for this problem like below:

`values.sure = Date.parse(sure);`

and I got "Ajax failure". My column type on SQL is bigint.

--> "sure" means time in Turkish.

Comment: You need to check that sure is not a number or null. You can only use substring on a string

Comment: I edited the question. I checked the number or null. @mplungjan

Comment: if you want an interger like 0344, you need to split and remove the :.  like  ```var sure = "03:44"; // turn it to string first
var output = sure.split(":").join("")
console.log(parseInt(output)) // then turn it back to int```

Comment: If you are using ExtJS (as your tag seems to suggest), there is a convenient function you can use: `if (Ext.isString(sure))`.